# Installing PECL package on Ubuntu -- cannot find config.m4

Tags: php, pecl, pear, ubuntu-11.10

I've got a new Ubuntu installation set up and running, it servers PHP pages on Apache, everything works normally.

I'm trying to install a PHP-PEAR package called [SCA_SDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sdo.installation.php), there's an issue with some programs I'm unfamiliar with such as phpize (prepares a PHP extension for compiling), and advanced features of the PECL install tool.

I have the following PHP packages intalled

- php5-cli
- php5-common
- php5-dev
- php-pear
- php5-xsl
- php5-xmlrpc

**Steps taken:**

```
$ sudo pecl install SCA_SDO
```

**Results**

```
downloading SCA_SDO-1.2.4.tgz ...
Starting to download SCA_SDO-1.2.4.tgz (576,531 bytes)
..............done: 576,531 bytes
194 source files, building
running: phpize
Cannot find config.m4.
Make sure that you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

If the command failed with 'phpize: not found' then you need to install php5-dev package
You can do it by running 'apt-get install php5-dev' as a root userERROR: `phpize' failed
```

`locate config.m4` turns up empty.

There's been a number of other questions on the internet that show this error, all describing weird "tricks" like execute `phpize` from the `/usr/bin` directory or some other thing, but none of these have really done any good here.

I've actually downloaded and ran make on pecl from source just to make sure it wasn't a bad package or something.

Not sure where to head from here, I can't get the .so module to install or run phpize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PHP 5.3 can't compile with this package.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58951)

Answer (score 1):

[config.m4 is located in the trunk](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/sdo/trunk/)

Maybe download and install without pecl? http://pecl.php.net/package/sca_sdo

Follow the readme in the packaged version: http://pecl.php.net/get/SCA_SDO

Comment: No such luck. I've reached a whole new level of problems where it fails the sanity checks on ./configure.

Comment: Why not paste the results from an attempt to ./configure

Comment: ./configure failed as G++ compiler was not installed with GCC at the time. Now I can't make without errors: https://raw.github.com/gist/1418910/92c5c95f339ef28a6abcd03210a7e3f72b4829a5/gistfile1.txt